# unit test HtmlHelper custom TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, html-helper

I have created an extension method that will return html helper TextBoxFor. Now I want to unit test that, but it throws "object reference not set to instance of an object".

**Extension Method**

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,     .......)
{

    /* some logic here */
    ===> (Null Exception) 
    return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(......);
}
```

The HtmlHelper mocking is correct because i have used it in several places.

Comment: Can you add some more code please.

Comment: more code for the extension method.

Comment: It'd help to see your unit test, because your problem is probably that you're not instantiating the `HtmlHelper` properly

Answer (score 7):

No need to mock the HtmlHelper. You could just create a fake view model class, for example TestViewModel and in your unit tests just do something like:

```
//-- Arrange
TestViewModel testViewModel = new TestViewModel()
            {
                Name = "sdfsd"
            };

IViewDataContainer dataContainerMock = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IViewDataContainer>();

dataContainerMock.ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<TestViewModel>(testViewModel);

HtmlHelper<TestViewModel> myHelper =  new HtmlHelper<TestViewModel>(new ViewContext()
            {
                ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<TestViewModel>(this._testViewModelWithoutMaxLength)
            }, this._dataContainerMock);

//-- Act 
MvcHtmlString result = //call your extension

//-- Assert 
//add asserts here
```

A little late but hope it still is ok for someone

Comment: where does MockRepository come from? Where can I find a test project?